# Service worker vs HTML5 Cache: either or

Tags: service-worker, html5-appcache

I need a website to cache data. And have set up both **Cache Storage** (via Service Worker) and **Application Cache** (via html manifest attribute). They work.

Question I have is to: how to ignore the Application Cache in case Server worker support exists on the browser?

Some reading on the internet suggests that Chrome ignores Application Cache if Cache storage works. I find it does not. **Chrome 63 on Mac OS X**.

One option seems to be to create a dynamic page (either keeping the manifest attribute or not) on the server based on the browser and OS type. Is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a service worker has activated, any existing Application Cache instances for the client pages that it controls are automatically unassociated. This behavior is described in step 6 of the Activate algorithm in the [service worker specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#activation-algorithm):

> For each service worker client client whose creation URL matches
>   registration’s scope url:
>
> 1. If client is a window client, unassociate client’s responsible
>      document from its application cache, if it has one.
> 2. Else if client is a shared worker client, unassociate client’s global
>      object from its application cache, if it has one.

If you're not seeing that behavior, and you're sure that the service worker activated and has control over a given client window, then that sounds like a bug in a browsers' implementation. You should follow up with details on reproduction steps on the appropriate browser's bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I did notice such a behaviour. But from your comments let me try it again step-by-step and confirm it. Also will share all details here. Thanks

Comment: I stand corrected @Jeff Posnick. Perhaps, the app cache was from an earlier settings. Thanks. Now a dual caching policy for both browser types will work.